# Emacs freezes when pressing ESC

Tags: debugging

My Emacs usually works well, but sometimes it freezes, to be more specific:

1. It only freezes after pressing ESC.
2. When the freeze begins, it will always freeze after pressing ESC: I kill Emacs, restart it, press ESC, then it freeze again. Unless I restart the the computer. After restarting, Emacs goes to normal again.
3. I can do nothing to bring it back to normal, including `C-g`, `pkill -USR2 emacs`, even `emacsclient -nw` in the terminal freezes.
4. `Emacs -Q` still freezes after pressing `ESC`.

Is there any way to find out the reason and solve it?

I'm using archlinux with GNU Emacs 27.1, this is `uname -a`:

```
Linux archlinux 4.19.18-1-lts #1 SMP Sat Jan 26 13:20:43 CET 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Try `strace -p <PID>` when it's frozen: you get the pid with `ps` or `top` or ... That should tell you where it is frozen, but that's only one small thing in trying to figure out the problem. But you have to start somewhere...

Comment: If you don't see the problem when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` then bisect your init file to hopefully find the culprit, i.e., to narrow the possibilities.

Comment: In a terminal, in a GUI, or both? Does it also do this in another terminal or in another graphical environment?

Comment: @Drew Do you mean my ~init~ file. I thought Emacs wouldn't parse my ~init~ file when starting with ~emacs -Q~.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Both, I used Terminator as the terminal and gnome3 as the GUI, haven't tried other terminals or graphical environment yet.

Comment: Yes. Use `emacs -Q` to start Emacs without using your init file. If you don't see the problem then, then it's caused by something in your init file. In that case, bisect your init file to find the problem. You can use command `comment-region` to comment out a block of code in your init file (and with `C-u` it uncomments the region). Comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, 31/32, etc. to find just the part that is problematic. If the needed fix is not clear then update your question, narrowing it to just the problematic code.

Comment: @Drew The question already states “Emacs -Q still freezes after pressing ESC.”

Comment: Looks like a pretty weird bug. Does Emacs react normally if you press `M-a`? If you press `C-[`? If you press `C-h Esc C-g`? Both in a terminal and GUI.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': Oh, right; sorry. In that case, OP should maybe consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by upgrading the Linux Kernel from 4.19 to 5.4. Not a perfect answer I know. But in case it's helpful for someone, I posted the answer here.